# My pure css accordion shifts sideways when one of the sections is opened and the chevrons at the side do not behave properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have built a pure CSS Bootstrap accordion on codepen. It is styled such that there is a button available for each section, which can be used to open and close the relevant section, as well as clicking on the section title. I have two issues with it, which I don't understand how to solve:

1. When you go from a state where all sections are closed to one of them being opened, there is a very slight shift to the left of the accordion, which is off-putting. When all sections are collapsed again, the accordion shifts back to the right. I can't work out why this is happening. Please could someone help me understand why and how to fix it?
2. The chevrons which are right-aligned are meant to point to the right when the section is collapsed and down when the section is expanded. When the accordion is initially loaded, before any sections are opened, all chevrons point downwards for some reason. Once one of them is opened, they behave normally. What am I doing wrong with them?

```css
.container {
  font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
}

.tiles {
  display: block;
  margin: 30px 0 30px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.tiles .button {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  margin: 0 0 30px 0;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid #0be4cb;
}

.tiles .button.turquoise {
  background: #0be4cb;
}

.tiles .button.turquoise:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #0be4cb;
  background: #fff;
}

.tiles .button.turquoise:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #0be4cb;
  background: #fff;
}

.panel {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.panel-group .panel {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.panel-group .panel+.panel {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.panel-default {
  border: none;
}

.panel-heading {
  padding: 20px 15px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.panel-heading .accordion-toggle {
  color: #333;
}

.panel-heading .accordion-toggle:hover {
  color: #0be4cb;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.panel-default>.panel-heading {
  color: #333;
  background: none;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.panel-default>.panel-heading+.panel-collapse>.panel-body {
  border: none;
}

.panel-heading .accordion-toggle:after {
  content: "\276F";
  float: right;
  color: grey;
  transition: all .35s;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.panel-heading .accordion-toggle.collapsed:after {
  content: "\276F";
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <!-Responsive Menu Buttons->
  <div class="tiles">
    <!-Button Row->
    <div class="row">
      <!-Menu Button 1->
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
        <a class="collapsed button turquoise" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseONE" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseONE">
            Category 1
            </a>
      </div>
      <!-End of Menu Button 1->
      <!-Menu Button 2->
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
        <a class="collapsed button turquoise" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTWO" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTWO">
            Category 2
            </a>
      </div>
      <!-End of Menu Button 2->
      <!-Menu Button 3->
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
        <a class="collapsed button turquoise" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTHREE" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTHREE">
            Category 3
            </a>
      </div>
      <!-End of Menu Button 3->
    </div>
    <!-End of Button Row->
  </div>
  <!-End of Responsive Menu Buttons->
  <!-Information Panel Group->
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">

    <!-Panel for Category 1->
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseONE">
                Category 1
              </a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseONE" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <h5>Text For Category One</h5>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis interdum facilisis magna, nec mattis ante gravida ac. Integer et est non tortor ultricies feugiat. Nam aliquam eros sit amet diam dictum tristique. Integer sodales tellus ut feugiat
            ornare. Suspendisse augue tellus, laoreet at mauris eu, placerat consequat urna. Aliquam porttitor quis justo sed tincidunt. Cras congue leo luctus efficitur tempor. Etiam fringilla elementum augue, et semper est dignissim ut. Maecenas massa
            dui, efficitur id mi eget, dignissim cursus enim.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-End of Panel for Category 1->
    <!-Panel for Category 2->
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTWO">
                Category 2
              </a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseTWO" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <h5>Text For Category Two</h5>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis interdum facilisis magna, nec mattis ante gravida ac. Integer et est non tortor ultricies feugiat. Nam aliquam eros sit amet diam dictum tristique. Integer sodales tellus ut feugiat
            ornare. Suspendisse augue tellus, laoreet at mauris eu, placerat consequat urna. Aliquam porttitor quis justo sed tincidunt. Cras congue leo luctus efficitur tempor. Etiam fringilla elementum augue, et semper est dignissim ut. Maecenas massa
            dui, efficitur id mi eget, dignissim cursus enim.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-End of Panel for Category 2->
    <!-Panel for Category 3->
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTHREE">
                Category 3
              </a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseTHREE" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <h5>Text For Category Three</h5>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis interdum facilisis magna, nec mattis ante gravida ac. Integer et est non tortor ultricies feugiat. Nam aliquam eros sit amet diam dictum tristique. Integer sodales tellus ut feugiat
            ornare. Suspendisse augue tellus, laoreet at mauris eu, placerat consequat urna. Aliquam porttitor quis justo sed tincidunt. Cras congue leo luctus efficitur tempor. Etiam fringilla elementum augue, et semper est dignissim ut. Maecenas massa
            dui, efficitur id mi eget, dignissim cursus enim.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-End of Panel for Category 3->

  </div>
  <!-End of Information Panel Group->
</div>
```

If you would prefer, here is the codepen link:

https://codepen.io/jgolding94/pen/LYZoZrW

Comment: Just FYI, these “pure CSS solutions” usually have severe usability issues. You are not doing users of assistive technology any favors with those. The BS JavaScript accordions set the necessary ARIA attributes via scripting to reflect the current state, but with such a “pure CSS solution” that is completely missing.

Comment: This displacement is due to the appearance of the scrollbar.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't notice that. Thanks!